# gqlplus Too many open files

Tags: sqlplus

When compiling gqlplus.sf.net it throws:

> Too many open files

What is causing this? After make, I usually do a

> cp gqlplus sqlplus

Comment: you can submit your answer to yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

Being a front-end for sqlplus, gqlplus needs the sqlplus executable to run. gqlplus looks for sqlplus in `$PATH` first, followed by `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`, followed by the local directory.

Comment: I'm posting this answer that the OP added into their question, as per [this Meta question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i)